# Checkmarx flag [Missing_Column_Encryption] in SqlConnection object constructor

Tags: c#, sql-server, security, owasp, checkmarx

I use **Checkmarx** to scan my `.NET6` WebApi project with [owasp top 10 - 2017](https://owasp.org/www-pdf-archive/OWASP_Top_10-2017_%28en%29.pdf.pdf)

It always flag a [Missing_Column_Encryption](https://uucscrp3.uitctech.com.tw/cxwebclient/ScanQueryDescription.aspx?queryID=100015&queryVersionCode=6051825137&queryTitle=Missing_Column_Encryption) Weakness, but the flagged code looks normal and does not have relation to `Missing_Column_Encryption`

here is the flagged code block

```cs
   //  the DecryptConn and Open() was flagged
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_securityHelp.DecryptConn(_config.GetConnectionString("InsuranceAgents"))))
            {
                //  was flagged
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
                {
```

The `_securityHelp.DecryptConn()` is a AES decrypt function which can help me to get connection string in the `appsettings.json`.

the image from checkmarx
[image]

##### Other description

This is my checkmarx's preset and setting
[image]

The OWASP TOP 10 - 2017 preset
[image]
[image]

My **DecryptConn** function

```cs
   try
            {
                var inputBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
                var engine = new RijndaelEngine(256);
                var blockCipher = new CbcBlockCipher(engine);
                CipherUtilities.GetCipher("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
                IBufferedCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(blockCipher, new Pkcs7Padding());
                var keyParam = new KeyParameter(key);
                var keyParamWithIv = new ParametersWithIV(keyParam, iv, 0, 32);
                cipher.Init(false, keyParamWithIv);
                var outputBytes = new byte[cipher.GetOutputSize(inputBytes.Length)];
                var length = cipher.ProcessBytes(inputBytes, outputBytes, 0);
                cipher.DoFinal(outputBytes, length); //Do the final block
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(outputBytes).Split('\0')[0];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return data;
            }
```

#### Tried

Had tried move the `_securityHelp()` method out, like this

```cs
   //  the DecryptConn and Open() was flagged
string connStr = _securityHelp.DecryptConn(_config.GetConnectionString("InsuranceAgents"))
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                //  was flagged
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
                {
```

But it was the same.

---

The `DecryptConn` trace to the `Open()` which is before starting the DB operation.
But I don't know why these code was flagged

Comment: Does this help? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5551f491-fafc-45ad-b089-5443f252d159/column-encryption-as-part-of-vulnerability-scanning-of-aspnet-project?forum=aspsecurityandvulnerability

Comment: I also studied this before. But this is discussing the DB's data can not pull after adding the `Integrated Security=true; Column Encryption Setting=enabled"`. At the mean time, I don't have my database info directly write in code like `string connStr = "Data Source=...;"`, I use decrypt function to get the connection string in appsettings.json. 
Or does this also can not be pass in checkmarx ? but the error flow looks like is the `Decrypt` problem.

Comment: Your `DecryptConn` code has issues....

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly the issues is? The `DecryptConn` method decrypt the connection string and give it to `SqlConnection` object's constructor, so I really need add `Column Encryption Setting=enabled` attribute to connection string?

Comment: Yes. Use `IDbConnection` instead of `SqlConnection`. But this solution can not use bulk  sql because only `SqlConnection` have bulk sql method